# linux: cut & print specific parameters from single line XML string

Tags: regex, linux, sed, grep, xmlstarlet

i have below string i.e., produced by my other Ansible-playbook URI module, which looks like XML but not actually. It is single line string starting from XML header to tail.

`echo $log`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n<response>\n <data>\n <configElement>\n <elementType>access-control</elementType>\n <attribute>\n <name>realm-id</name>\n <value>Core</value>\n </attribute>\n <attribute>\n <name>realm-id</name>\n <value>REC12-CL1</value>\n </attribute>\n <attribute>\n <name>realm-id</name>\n <value>REC12-ML1</value>\n </attribute>\n <attribute>\n <name>last-modified-date</name>\n <value>2017-11-28 16:47:31</value>\n </attribute>\n </configElement>\n </data>\n <messages/>\n <links/>\n</response>\n
```

how can i fetch `<realm-id>` and its very next value `<value>` from above string.

i have already tried `greo -o` & some `sed` `cut` methods, but no luck.

please help.

expected output is something like

```
realm-id,Core
realm-id,REC12-CL1
realm-id,REC12-ML1
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use xpath for this:

```
xmllint --xpath '//name/text()|//value/text()' xmldatafile |
  awk '(NR%2)!=0{n=$0}(NR%2)==0{v=$0;print n,v}' OFS=,
```

---

```
realm-id,Core
realm-id,REC12-CL1
realm-id,REC12-ML1
last-modified-date,2017-11-28 16:47:31
```

Then, you can filter this list with grep or whatever